# ExecuteScript method

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Basically I'm trying to do a little chrome extension following Google documentation. I'd like to inject a script every time the extension button is clicked.
This is my manifest so far:

```
    {
  "name": "Example",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "description": "My Chrome extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

And this is my background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "content_script.js"});
});
```

The problem is that the content_script is not fired, even trying with such a simple `alert("aaa");`

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to execute a content script on a page, you must request the correct host permissions in your manifest file.

Since you want to insert a content script on click of a browser action button, it suffices to request the [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html). Furthermore, you can drop the `tabs` permission, to reduce the number of [permission warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html) to zero!

```
{
  "name": "Example",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

(The `activeTab` permission has been [introduced in Chrome 26](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#26). If you need to support Chrome 25 and earlier, add the `*://*/*` or `<all_urls>` permissions to the manifest file).

Note: If you add a callback to [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript), you would have received a useful error message in [`chrome.runtime.lastError.message`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError):

> Cannot access contents of url "http....." Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: "content_script.js"
    }, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this make the trick and also thank you for exception handling. This response is very exhaustive.

Comment: Isn't the "content_script.js" that I lauched supposed to be able to edit current tab content? It doesn't seem so. For example I can retreive textbox value but not to set it.

Comment: @fillobotto You should be able to set the value. Can you show what you're trying?

Comment: Oh, just a simple line of code: `document.getElementById('textboxid').value = 'mytext'`

Comment: @fillobotto That bit of code should work. Make sure that the page itself is not also setting the `value` property. If you're still troubled, consider asking a new question with all details: The page you're acting on, the code you're using, and the code you're using to insert the content script.

Comment: It's interesting, the same code is now working. I think I changed another piece of code without noticing it. Well, we can consider this thread closed, thank you Rob W.

Comment: @RobW, Btw if there is no warning for `activeTab` permission, then why do you even need to apply for it? Shouldn't it have been activated by default?

Comment: @Pacerier It's better for security to have fine-grained control over capabilities.

Comment: @RobW, Are you referring to that in the future Chrome (or another Chromium browser) may decide to give a warning for `activeTab` permissions? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @Pacerier No, I'm just saying that the existence of the permission allows the browser to only provide the functionality when an extension asks for it in advance. If an extension without the permission has a code execution vulnerability, then at least it cannot abuse the permissions that it did not ask for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Rob's fix you should be using `{file: "content_script.js"}`

Comment: Well-spotted. Currently `content_scripts.js` is seen as code instead of a file, because `"code"` was used instead of `"file`" - see [`chrome.tabs`#InjectDetails](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-InjectDetails)