# Chrome Extension executeScript fails silently

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to execute some code inside of a content page from the background page, but it fails silently.  I can debug through and see a breakpoint hitting the executeScript line.

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status === 'complete' ) {

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            file: "alerter.js"          
        },
        function( result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

alerter.js:

```
alert("is this thing on?");
```

Section of manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery.min.js",
    "jquery.min.map",
   "alerter.js"
],
```

Any ideas guys?  I should also note that in the results callback, result is undefined but the callback does run.

**Update:**

Ok, so, I found that if I put "<all_urls>" into the permissions section of the manifest, it works.  That's probably not a good thing.  If I put "alerter.js" into the permissions section, the extension fails to load with:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension: 
Permission 'alerter.js' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
```

What's the correct permission here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecuteScript method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011733/executescript-method)

Comment: @RobW this doesn't seem a duplicate of that question, as the OP is trying to inject the script in a `tabs.onUpdated` event, not a browser action or context menu event.

Comment: @Darthg8r if you want to be able to programmatically execute a content script on every page without user intervention, then you certainly need the `<all_urls>` permission.

Comment: @rsanchez Although the questions are not identical duplicates, the underlying problem is identical: The lack of host permissions. The accepted answer shows an (admittedly not relevant to this question) special case for the question (`activeTab` permission), but then it continues with a more general answer (`*://*/*` permission) plus debugging tips for such problems. IMO, the similarity of the question and usefulness of the existing answer justifies this question to be marked as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @RobW you only mention the `*://*/*` permission to support older Chrome versions which did not have the `activeTab` permission. There is no hint that you will need it to programmatically execute a content script on arbitrary pages without user intervention.

Comment: @rsanchez That hint you're looking for is the first line of the answer. Anyway, if you feel that your comment provides a better answer to the question than the possible duplicate, post it as an answer.

Comment: ActiveTab only applies if I'm manipulating the current tab.  That won't always be the case.  Am I left with <all_urls> then?

Comment: @Darthg8r you should use the pattern that requires access for the least amount of domains possible so that users are less likely to get scared away. You can see spec for URI patterns [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: As a comment, to debug async calls to Chrome API you often need to examine `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback. So it doesn't fail "silently", there's just no exception raised.